# Realm: imported data are shown as String type not Int

Tags: swift, csv, realm, xlsx

I have a problem with builded realm. When I am importing CSV or XLSX file to realm browser, it will generate a "default.realm" file and mark the columns with Integer values as String, but i need it as Int type, because a need to perform .max() function on it.

[image]

When i define in object class like this

```
let price = RealmOptional<Int>()
```

.. it will crash.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in current version of Realm Browser unfortunately :( I've created https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/210 to track it.